# What should you do when your professor does not pay you for completed research work?

Tags: research-process, masters, etiquette, supervision

I had an oral agreement with a supervisor that I was to complete research work for him. We established how many hours I was to work, and my hourly rate, when the work was to be done, etc. I completed the work, sent it off to him, he gave me some feedback and asked me to correct some citations and so, I incorporated the feedback, made fixes to my citations and then never heard back from him.

I recently emailed him about not being paid; he told me that he was not able to use the work and instead offered to find me alternative funding opportunities in the future. When I insisted that I did the work and deserved to get paid for my time, he threatened to report me for academic integrity issues. I'm only a Master's student, and this is my first research assistant position. Is this normal? Who should I speak to about this?

I am not part of a union, and my supervisor approached me to do this work. I do have email correspondence that confirms we have an agreement, but not confirming the specific terms (e.g. he wrote emails where he told me, submit your work and your time/hour log and I will pay you). He later revealed he had used the grant money to pay a different student to do different work.

The oral contract was made in front of others. It was in a lab setting, so others definitely overheard. Another clarification was that another student was to take over the work I began because I was going on an exchange to a different school. So there is more proof of a contract existing between my supervisor and me. My #1 concern is the threat of reporting me for academic integrity. My #2 concern is getting paid. I've contacted my faculty and was advised to report this to the dean of my faculty, which I'll be doing shortly.

Comment: Which country is this in?

Comment: @Scared-scarecrow And you still have the time log, and record of submitting it? How much are we talking about here? Not to say you aren't owed it no matter how much, but approaching getting $400 is very different than $5000

Comment: I have edited the post to transfer some useful clarifications from the comments into the post itself. I also removed a ton of answers-in-comments; please use the answer box for answers.

Comment: On a related note, what did we learn about oral contracts?

Comment: I recommend getting hard copies (i.e. print-outs) of all of the e-mail correspondence (in case your e-mails disappear from their servers - not likely, but possible).

Comment: "This is my first research assistant position": that is not a "research assistant position", it is just an intellectual property theft!

Comment: Do you have any idea what sort of "academic integrity issues" he's threatening to report you for?

Comment: I am also interested in what the "academic integrity issues" are supposed to be. (Also: let us know, how this turned out.)

Comment: @Valorum As George R R Martin put it: "Words are wind".

Answer (score 62):

> Is this normal?

No.  In most places, wage theft is a serious crime.

> Who should I speak to about this?

The HR department.  Possibly also the department chair.  Provide a detailed written statement of what happened and when.

Comment: +1 for going to the institution's HR department. It's a chronic problem that academics and researchers will make ad-hoc hires without going through proper process, and HR will have people whose whole jobs are to sort out the messes that they create. You may end up being owed benefits because the nature of your work falls into a category which they've already categorized. Best case for you (*worst ever* for the supervisor) is if your tasks fell into a category within the scope of a contract of an existing union.

Comment: Good point, if there's a union you might speak to them too.  Though you might need to pay a membership fee.

Comment: Also contact student support, the person in charge of your masters, and any personal tutor that you may have. The PI, in addition to acting appallingly unethically by not paying you and by threatening you, may well have broken the University's own rules by employing you without contract and proper process.

Comment: Should contact both parties mentioned in the order mentioned. Talking to the student union would probably also be beneficial. Once HR is involved the chair won't have option but to investigate. However, keep in mind that HR is **NOT** your friend.

Comment: I was in a similar situation (1 month's coding work for a professor of a _different university_ with a view for a grant together down the line), but HR, not the professor, was the issue. HR was definitely not my friend. The verbal contract was in conflict with all sorts rules and regulations so they could not pay and the professor was too busy to fight it —so I politely declined to submit the grant and cut my losses.

Comment: An Oral Agreement, with presumably no third parties to witness the agreement. Good luck collecting anything. This will just become a mud-slinging fest, with the student's word vs. the professor's.

Comment: As others have suggest - the prof almost certainly did not have the power to make a contract between you and the university (you would have been employed by the university, not by the professor). The likely outcome is that the professor will be in deep trouble with the university, but in the end the professor is not in a position to make a contract on the university's behalf, and so it is probably not valid.

Comment: @IanSudbery: I'm not so sure about your last statement - at the very least it will depend very much on legislation. Here in Germany, I'd think it quite likely that the student has a valid employment contract with the university.  But even if not, they are still entitled to either fulfilment or damages (which would be the same since they already fulfilled their part of the contract).

Comment: Almost certainly depends on the location, and IANAL, but in the UK its not possible for just any old employee to enter into a contract on behalf of an organisation. Would you think the same if it were a postdoc saying this rather than a professor? If so, what would be the legal difference?

Comment: @IanSudbery: At least at the universities where I have been, it is quite possible for the professor to do most of the *correct* administrative work without the student seeing any of this, in partiular for the small HiWi (student assistant) contracts. Legally, a professor (or a postdoc) can have implicit or explicit permission to hire a student on behalf of the university. A professor saying "I'll hire you as student assistant." would not be unusual at all - even if the actual employer is the university. "Expect  administration to take some months until this all is sorted out, and several more

Comment: more months until you actually see any money" would be a usual follow up sentence, but you really cannot conclude anything about the professor being in bad faith from this not being said. A professor over here is a public official whose job is to teach the student how academia works. That is a very strong position for the student assuming good faith. Postdoc offereing a job: Two relevant differences are that a professor always has at least some budget, and that the postdoc is subordinate to a professor - while the professor is not subordinate to anyone (though of course still bound by rules).

Comment: So the postdoc should say or show that they have a budget and permission to hire someone, but then: why not. E.g. if there's an ad on the whiteboard "student help wanted for ..., Dr Postdoc" Also, the professor is usually the "contact" employee at the university that manages the student help. HR would certainly expenct the professor to be the one to tell a student to not work if they erraneously show up for work in order to prevent a *valid* employment contract forming by conduct implying intent. The example we were warned aganist by administration is: someones fixed term contract expires. New

Comment: contract has not yet arrived. The "[non]employee" comes to work, and the PI/professor does not tell them to go home, or even worse, actively hands out work or collects results. This starts a valid *permanent* working contract and is the nightmare of HR.

Comment: I guess its location dependent. Yes a prof might say what your prof said, but they would then initiate the process with the admin - but its the admin that actually does the "hire" even if the student never sees this. The university has not agreed to employ someone until HR says so. A prof here is absolutely subordinate to someone - their HoD, their head of faculty and ultimately the senate and executive board. They are not a public official, they are an employee of a corporation like any other employee - same *legal* rights and responsibilities as the cleaner.

Comment: The university might have budgeted for the Prof to spend money, but the money remains the property of the university. Even if the Prof can request they spend it on something (probably through an automated mechanism for a simple purchase), they still retain the final say and can say no. Only the university can raise a purchase order with a supplier for example, the prof can't on their own.

Answer (score 19):

No, this is not normal. If an agreement about number of working hours and an hourly salary is made, the salary is normally supposed to be paid according to that agreement.

It is not clear to me if a contract was written up, or if everything was oral agreements. If there is no contract, and no written correspondence to confirm the agreement, you will unfortunately have a hard time lifting this case. But in any case, the correct person to contact (which is your question), is your union, or a local union representative at your institution - that is, if unions are common in your country, which you don't mention.

If you are not a member of a union, you should become so if that is a possibility.

You should also start looking for another supervisor, as this person clearly don't have your best interest in mind.

Answer (score 9):

You *should* report this to a some authority.

The chances are good (but we do not know this) that the person has done this before and will do it again.  Ethically if you have evidence enough to make a formal complaint you should to prevent them exploiting people.  Ethically and practically are, however, two different things - you will have to make the decision yourself.

> he wrote emails where he told me, submit your work and your time/hour log and I will pay you

That is sufficient grounds to take a complaint case.  It is borderline whether it is enough to successfully take a legal case for failing to pay against them.  It is not quite a contract (IANAL) I think, as the terms would be explicit (e.g. how much per hour or in total) for a contract.  If you have corresponding emails now saying he will not pay that would be much stronger.

Strictly speaking you need legal advice specific to you country from your own lawyer.

Do not expect to ever get paid.  You can possibly put an end to this person's behavior (by *maybe* getting them fired), but getting paid is not so easy.

> I recently emailed him about not being paid;

Email is your friend here.  Hopefully the replies were in email.

Make records of any emails, e.g. print them, copy them to disk.  Get copies of texts by phone or whatsapp fs whatever if possible and try and get recordings of any phone messages left for you.

Courts and formal review processes will need evidence like this.

> he told me that he was not able to use the work

This is rarely a legitimate complaint in a labor case (which is what you would probably have here - again IANAL).  If your work was OK up until you asked for payment a court would typically take that as a demonstration your work was OK and without fundamental flaw.  There would have to be a history of consistent complaint from the other person to justify not paying.  They should also have stopped using you to assist them to be able to defend their position.  Stopping after you ask for payment they refuse to make is too late.

> and instead offered to find me alternative funding opportunities in the future.

That is known as "bait and switch", it's not considered reasonable.  You expected to be paid, but unfortunately did not have an explicit agreement on the form of that payment, so it might be a slight weak point.

> When I insisted that I did the work and deserved to get paid for my time, he threatened to report me for academic integrity issues.

If he was foolish enough to do that in email, you have an extremely serious case against him for abuse of power.  He was acting an an employee of an institute and your supervisor so that is a case you can directly take against them.  Typically you would make a formal complaint first via the institute's normal procedure.  I would expect that to be enough to put this individual in danger of loosing their job - I'd personally fire someone for doing this (when good evidence existed), but your institute and country's normal practices are unknown to me.

Make sure you have good legal advice for this process.  Join a union and request their help and advice - they typically have a legal representative they can at least put you in touch with, sometimes for reduced fees or free as an initial step.  If that is not an opinion get your own lawyer.

Comment: I have to remind you that even VERBAL agreements are contracts - or contract-like .. unfortunately harder to prove than written contracts - except made in front of third parties

Comment: @eagle275 My understanding is that the OP has emails, so verbal contracts or agreements would have practically no significance here.  Any written agreement will override a verbal one and you cannot amend a written agreement (or an agreement in a similar form) with a verbal one.  So if we agreed by email to do X for Y, then later neither of us would be able to enforce a verbal change to that agreement - it would have to be by email or in writing.  That's the law as I understand it, but IANAL.

Comment: No my comment is based on the post of OP - he says that the exact amount and conditions were agreed upon only verbally - which still constitutes a contract - then he has emails about "correct X and hand in your hours and I'll pay you" which supports the argument of the verbal agreement/ contract ..

Comment: @eagle275 As I said in my answer, the emails are not quite an explicit contract, but my point was that the supervisor's emails effectively acknowledged the contract in writing and trying to undo the contract (and make threats) means that the supervisor's claims will carry practically zero weight compared to the written evidence of emails.

Comment: @eagle275 IANAL, but professors are not employers, universities are. Given that a professor has no authority to make contracts on the university's behalf, I doubt the contract is valid. For example someone who worked front of house at McDonald's couldn't make a contract with a customer for MacDonald's to employ them at head office. I doubt the situation is any different with a prof and a student,  legally (but not ethically) speaking.

Comment: @IanSudbery Really hard to know what interpretation a court would take on these details as it's very jurisdiction dependent and also depends on the standard practices and reasonable expectations people can have.  This is why so many of us have recommended the OP speak to a local lawyer, preferably via a union as they'll have more specific knowledge of local case law on this.

Comment: @StephenG Well,  I'd definately always recommend joining and using a union if one is available.

Comment: @IanSudbery If the contract is not valid for the reason you state, might the student have a case of fraud against the professor? He presented himself as a representative of the university with the power to hire and pay people. If the student does not in fact have a contract with the university, then it would seem that the professor's indication that he had the power to make that contract was fraudulent in the first place. I'd have no recourse against McDonald's for someone who pretends to enter into contracts on their behalf, but I'd expect to have recourse against that person.

Comment: @NuclearWang - That would be hard to call fraud unless the professor explicitly said that the *university* would pay the student. In the absence of such an explicit statement it could also be interpreted as a private contract between the professor and student (outsourcing the work, essentially), forcing the professor to pay out of his own pocket.

Comment: @IanSudbery A professor can absolutely be an employer. The professor can have problems getting the university to pay his employee, which means he or she would have to pay the employee out of their own pocket. Most professors are wise enough to avoid that situation. And the way this particular contract is described, I see no indication that the university would be involved in any way.

Comment: @NuclearWang: (for jurisdiction Germany) the student has the right to get fulfillment of the contract or damages. From the professor, if there was no valid contract with the university. However, there may actually be a valid contract with the university here - this would depend on the details. E.g. if the university has let the professor hire students in a similar manner before, that would count as the university granting the professor the power to hire on their behalf.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** Try your *local small claims court or arbitration service* to claim your salary, and make a formal complaint to your university regarding the professor's threat.

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, I'm an academic too. Try to look up guidelines specific to your jurisdiction. Don't worry about what may be common in academia. Pay disputes are very common in every field of life, and your situation isn't that different to if a car wash or a restaurant tried not to pay you for work already completed.

**The full answer**

There are two issues here - firstly getting the money you are owed, and secondly dealing with your professor's threat of retaliation.

Although the exact processed will vary from country to country, I would suggest this as a somewhat universal blueprint to get the money you are owed.

1. **Compile all evidence in writing.** Make an annotated PDF of all the emails where your agreement is mentioned. Email people who were present at the meeting when you agreed the hourly rate, asking "Hey, just sorting out some project stuff. You were there when I set an hourly rate if X Euros with professor Y. Just wanted to check you remember that this was the amount we agreed on." From their replies, you now have evidence of the oral agreement in writing too.
2. Email a **formal final request for payment** to your professor. Keep it brief (don't go into your whole dispute), and include payment details and a date by when you expect payment.
3. If the professor still refuses to pay, **file a claim with your local small claims court or arbitration service**. Small pay disputes are very common, and these kinds of services are designed to be cheap and efficient to use. For example, in the UK the fee to submit a claim is ~20GBP. Evidence (i.e. your annotated set of emails) is submitted online to an arbiter who will try to reach an agreement between the parties. No need for lawyers, and most cases can be resolved online or by phone, with no need to go into a court. In general you won't have the opportunity to call witnesses in this kind of arbitration, so make sure you have all your evidence (including the emails from witnesses) in a PDF or on paper.

The threat of academic retaliation by your professor is another issue, and a very serious one. Was this threat made in writing? If so, I would immediately make a formal complaint to the university. This will pre-empt any possible retaliation on the professor's part. If the threat was not made in writing, you may not want to make a complaint at this stage - however by formally pursuing the money you are owed, you will have demonstrated that he has a conflict of interest if he ever does decide to make a complaint against you.

Comment: In the UK specifically, to initiate a case like this you must go through the ACAS service (Advisory, Conciliation and Arbitration Service). They have a very helpful phoneline you can phone to be guided through the process. They'll also be able to tell you exactly what the law is as it relates to the case.